# How to write a custom Gazebo plugin for ROS?

Tags: gazebo, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello! I was wondering how can I write a custom gazebo plugin for ROS , preferably in Python?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/287068/how-to-write-a-custom-gazebo-plugin-for-ros-?/) by [sezan92](https://answers.ros.org/users/29788/sezan92/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2018-03-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-30**:
Gazebo plugins are C++ only afaik.

**Comment by [sezan92](https://answers.ros.org/users/29788/sezan92/) on 2018-03-31**:
How to write in C++ then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure how up-to-date it is (especially with the recent releases of newer versions in the `7.x` and `8.x` series of Gazebo), but [gazebosim.org/Tutorial: Ros Plugins](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_plugins) would seem to be the "hello world" of writing Gazebo plugins that integrate with ROS (with [gazebosim.org/Tutorial: Using Gazebo plugins with ROS](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_gzplugins) showing how to configure your urdf/sdf to include the plugins in a model/sim).

I would also recommend to take a look at [gazebo_ros_pkgs](http://wiki.ros.org/gazebo_ros_pkgs) (source: [ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs)) as that package provides most of the standard Gazebo-ROS plugins. Personally I find reading other peoples sources very informative.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-03-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Akash Purandare](https://answers.ros.org/users/34280/akash-purandare/) on 2018-04-01**:
You could also refer to Gazebo API in the following link. http://gazebosim.org/api.html

**Comment by [fozzy-b](https://answers.ros.org/users/47896/fozzy-b/) on 2019-11-22**:
It appears as if the velodyne tutorial is out of date - the gazebo plugins do not include a velodyne plugin, and the plugins as of kinetic / melodic appear to follow camel casing, rather than the Pythonic underscore (looked in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gazebo-x/plugins